# How can I add multiple dates with same item having a primary key

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to develop a Windows Forms application for a medical shop.

I have some tables:

1. `Users`
2. `Dealers`
3. `Item_master`
4. `Stock_items`

I have a date field in `[stock_items]`.

I have `item_id` as a primary_key in `[stock_items]`, and as a foreign key in tables `[item_master]` and `[stock_items]`.

So now when I add new item to the stock it will get added over the already existing item into the stock.

For example, if some item was already in record with quantity=3 and I add 10 more items to it, the total number of items will be 13.

But the expiry date can be different for new items than existing items.

Please suggest some solutions.

Thank you.

Comment: IF I understood you correctly, you can check if item with id already exists. If yes, get it and add to it stock items... if not, create and stock items to it.

Comment: @demo no the records can't be duplicated because stock items have item_id as primary key also but thanks for answering

Comment: I thought `item_id` is FK in `stock_items`. PK in `Item_master`

Comment: @demo no. it's primary key in both table and also foreign key in stock_items

Comment: oh... ok, as @kkktje suggested, the easiest solution to add new PK to `stock_items`. Then you can easily handle one-to-many relationship

Comment: You have to post all classes including the relations too  if you really need some help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to add a new primary key,
You can use the existing `item_id` as a foreign_key.

```
Table [stock_items]

item_seq (Primary key) = identity count

item_id  (foreign_key)

..

..
```